# Prevent the 'Notification Bar Fiesta'

Tags: feature-request, notifications

This is similar to [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta) on MSO, but happens at AskUbuntu. As a double treat, it's the same message twice AND the bounty was already awarded!

[image]
Could this be prevented?

Comment: Would the [meta-tag:bug] tag be appropriate here?

Comment: @WarriorIng64, I changed the tag. At the time of writing, I hadn't awarded the bounty (my mistake), however, at this moment the bounty has been awarded and I still see one of the notification bars (I closed the other).

Answer (score 1):

How is this a "bug"? Both messages were sent to you and were valid at the appropriate time.

If you want them collapsed, that's a feature request. And not a really big deal, is it?

Comment: IMO only the "expires in the next 24 hours" message should be shown. It's true that both messages were valid at the time shown, but only because, as the OP pointed out, they were redundant and just taking up screen space needlessly. But as you said, it's not a major issue, as the notifications can be closed easily. It doesn't impact usability of the site, but it does look weird.

Comment: Jeff, as @WarriorIng64 indicates, it's redundant. As for usability, IMO the notification bars are one click too much at all times, but it's a minor issue and on MSO it's considered a non-issue. I believe most MSO users are not interested in usability. It's a pity because with some minor tweaks, StackExchange usability could be more awesome than it already is.